# Deploy rdiff-backup to ESXi server

Tags: vmware-esxi, rdiff-backup

Have someone succeeded to deploy rdiff-backup to ESXi platform? If yes, are there any instructions how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

it's not really rdiff-backup deployment but i:

1. use [ghettoVCB](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8760) to transfer via NFS backups of vms from esxi to another machine in the same lan
2. run [rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/) to create backup with 2 weeks of diffs
3. rsync created repository to remote site